# mix Download and Unzip progress into one TotalProgress

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a electron-node downloader module and need to show the progress.
This process contains 2 parts. The download part and the unzip part.
I have both progresses working fine from 1 to 100, but separeted.

I want the user to not be bothered by the unzip part, but still see the progress in some form.

So i was thinking of having a totalProgress of 100 formed of 90% download 10% unzip.

Not sure if any code will help here, but i will try to add some numbers.

```
Downloading progress: 1,2,3,...100   
Unzipping progress: 1,2,3...100
```

So basically i'm trying to merge these 2 progresses into 1:

```
Total progress : Downloading 90% + Unzipping 10%
```

If anyone has an idea how to do it please, cose i can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Can we really make those processes parallel? I used to think that you have to download a file first, then unzip it. So, a notation like `Downloading 90% + Unzipping 10%` confuses me. It looks like a program is already unzipping a not fully downloaded file.

Comment: The process in not parralel, the steps are clear. First Downloading the file and then Unzipping. I just want to show only one progess for the whole thing and don't know how i could change 100 + 100 into a big 100 formed of 90+10 :D

Comment: The libraries that i'm using are still gona send me the progress from 1 to 100 and i need to mix them together into one progress.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?